# Promise.each without bluebird

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I need using `Promise.each` on **bluebird**. But when I see the bundle files, I'm actually thinking twice using **bluebird** or not.

Can anyone give me an example using function like **bluebird** `Promise.each` without dependencies.

Comment: FTR - bluebird has partial and custom builds - you can get it as low as 5kb

Comment: How can I do that? trying to import `require(bluebird/each)` not work

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Sure:

```
Promise.each = function(arr, fn) { // take an array and a function
  // invalid input
  if(!Array.isArray(arr)) return Promise.reject(new Error("Non array passed to each"));
  // empty case
  if(arr.length === 0) return Promise.resolve(); 
  return arr.reduce(function(prev, cur) { 
    return prev.then(() => fn(cur))
  }, Promise.resolve());
}
```

Or with modern JS (Chrome or Edge or with a transpiler):

```
Promise.each = async function(arr, fn) { // take an array and a function
   for(const item of arr) await fn(item);
}
```

Comment: Note that 'empty case' will never be tested here as 0 is falsy, so `!arr.length` will cause empty arrays to be rejected as a non-array rather than resolved.

Better using `!(arr instanceof Array)`.

Comment: The `empty check` is unnecessary because `Array.prototype.reduce()` will return `initialValue` (`Promise.resolve()` here) if the array is empty. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Will these functions be called in parallel or in series? (Will the second call to fn only happen once the first call has completed?)

Answer (score -3):

If we look at the `Promise` documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), you can see there's two methods we would be able to use. `all` and `race`, the former finishes when all promises are resolved where the latter finishes when the first promise resolves.

This should give you the tools to do everything you could do with bluebirds `Promise.each`. If it doesn't solve your problem yet, please state your concrete problem and I'll see if I can help you out.

Comment: This answer would be a better comment. But most importantly it is not accurate in the way that `Promise.each` works (predictably ordered operations that fire asynchronously). Both `Promise.all` and `Promise.race` do not provide any idea of order (particularly `race`, which is "first one wins").