# How to load these iframes sequentially?

Tags: javascript

I have a big array of strings and each string should end up making/loading an iframe. The idea was to load each iframe sequentially: `iframe 1 loaded → start loading iframe 2... etc..`

I wanted to divide that load by dividing the array into chunks and running those in parallel. However, I can't figure out how to run the contents of each chunk sequentially in this setup.

1. Chunk[0] → Load iframe 1 → iframe 1 loaded → Load iframe 2 → iframe 2 loaded → done
2. Chunk[1] → Load iframe 3 → iframe 3 loaded → Load iframe 4 → iframe 4 loaded → done
3. Chunk[2] → Load iframe 5 → iframe 5 loaded → Load iframe 6 → iframe 6 loaded → done
4. Chunk[3] → Load iframe 7 → iframe 7 loaded → Load iframe 8 → iframe 8 loaded → done
5. Chunk[4] → Load iframe 9 → iframe 9 loaded → Load iframe 10 → iframe 10 loaded → done
6. And when all chunks are finished show the results.

How do I do that?

Right now my code does everything I want, except the sequential loading:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lollero/0bpoyrd8/)

```
var promiseArray = [];
var urlParams = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var maxLength = urlParams.length/5;
var chunks = divideArray( urlParams, maxLength );

for ( var chunkIndex=0; chunkIndex < chunks.length; chunkIndex++) {
    var urlParams = chunks[ chunkIndex ];
  console.log( 'Chunk-' + chunkIndex );
  for ( var paramIndex=0; paramIndex < urlParams.length; paramIndex++) {

    promiseArray.push(
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        var urlParam = urlParams[ paramIndex ];
        var iframe = $('<iframe src="https://gist.github.com/joonaspaakko/414c4a43ac092f562e07e1642fa75dc5.pibb?val=' + urlParam + '"></iframe>');
        iframe.prependTo('body');
        iframe.on("load", function() {
          // var iframeBody = iframe.contents().find('body');
          iframe.remove();

          console.log( 'Iframe-'+ urlParam );
          resolve( 'Iframe-'+ urlParam +' loaded.');
        });

      })
    )

  }
}


Promise.all( promiseArray ).then(function( result ) {
  console.log(result);
});


function divideArray( array, maxLength ) {
  var chunks = [];
  for ( var i=0; i < array.length; i+=maxLength ) {
    chunks.push( array.slice(i,i+maxLength) );
  }
  return chunks;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chaining asynchronous operations using raw promises is rather cumbersome, but here is how you can do it with `async` functions:

1. Extract the code that loads an iframe into an `async` function
2. Make another `async` function that sequentially calls the first one for every URL in a chunk.
3. The rest is more or less identical to the code you already have: call the chunk-processing function for every chunk and wait until all of them finish using `Promise.all`

   ```
   var promiseArray = [];
   var urlParams = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
   var maxLength = urlParams.length / 5;
   var chunks = divideArray(urlParams, maxLength);

   for (var chunkIndex = 0; chunkIndex < chunks.length; chunkIndex++) {
       var urlParams = chunks[chunkIndex];
       console.log('Chunk-' + chunkIndex);
       promiseArray.push(processChunk(urlParams));
   }

   Promise.all(promiseArray).then(function (result) {
       console.log(result);
   });


   async function processURL(urlParam) {
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           var iframe = $('<iframe src="https://gist.github.com/joonaspaakko/414c4a43ac092f562e07e1642fa75dc5.pibb?val=' + urlParam + '"></iframe>');
           iframe.prependTo('body');
           iframe.on("load", function () {
               console.log('Iframe-' + urlParam);
               resolve('Iframe-' + urlParam + ' loaded.');
           });
       });
   }


   async function processChunk(chunk) {
       var urlResults = [];
       for (var paramIndex = 0; paramIndex < urlParams.length; paramIndex++) {
           var urlResult = await processURL(chunk[paramIndex]);
           urlResults.push(urlResult);
       }
       return urlResults;
   }


   function divideArray(array, maxLength) {
       var chunks = [];
       for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += maxLength) {
           chunks.push(array.slice(i, i + maxLength));
       }
       return chunks;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use this handy utility function:

```
/**
 * Given an Iterable (an array, for example), or a promise of an Iterable,
 * iterates serially over all the values in it, executing the given iterator on each element.
 *
 * @tutorial https://stackoverflow.com/a/41608207/3563013
 * @tutorial http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html
 * @tutorial https://jsfiddle.net/mckabue/zmf3tL9k/11/ - you can queue mapped promises
 *
 * @param { Iterable<any> | Promise<Iterable<any>> } items
 * @param { Function } fn
 * @param {*} options
 */
export default function promiseEach(items, fn, options) {
    options = Object.assign({}, {
        continueOnFail: false,
        startValue: undefined,
        nonArrayError: "Non array passed to each",
        emptyArrayResolveValue: undefined
    }, options);
    // invalid input
    if (!Array.isArray(items)) {
        return Promise.reject(new Error(options.nonArrayError));
    }
    // empty case
    if (items.length === 0) {
        return Promise.resolve(options.emptyArrayResolveValue);
    }
    return items.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array) => {
        return accumulator[!!options.continueOnFail ? 'finally' : 'then'](function () {
            return fn(currentValue, currentIndex, array);
        });
    }, Promise.resolve(options.startValue));
}
```

See:

```js
function promiseEach(items, fn, options) {
    options = Object.assign({}, {
        continueOnFail: false,
        startValue: undefined,
        nonArrayError: "Non array passed to each",
        emptyArrayResolveValue: undefined
    }, options);
    // invalid input
    if (!Array.isArray(items)) {
        return Promise.reject(new Error(options.nonArrayError));
    }
    // empty case
    if (items.length === 0) {
        return Promise.resolve(options.emptyArrayResolveValue);
    }
    return items.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array) => {
        return accumulator[!!options.continueOnFail ? 'finally' : 'then'](function () {
            return fn(currentValue, currentIndex, array);
        });
    }, Promise.resolve(options.startValue));
};

promiseEach([1,2,3,4,5,6], function(i){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(i);
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });
}).then(() => console.log("DONE"));
```